# How to render image in React from buffer data fetched from mongo db collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image

I am fetching the logo image through axios from mongo db and getting the following logo image buffer data:

Existing RESULT.data [{"logo":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,5,4,4,5,4,3,5,5,4,5,6,6,5,6,8,14,9,8,7,7,8,17,12,13,10,14,20,17,21,20,19,17,19,19,22,24,31,27,22,23,30,23,19,19,27,37,28,30,32,33,35,35,35,21,26,38,41,38,34,41,31,34,35,34,255,219,0,67,1,6,6,6,8,7,8,16,9,9,16,34,22,19,22,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,255,194,0,17,8,2,160,4,26,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,28,0,0,1,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,255,196,0,26,1,1,0,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,16,3,16,0,0,1,236,160,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,194,240,212,245,77,35,64,86,155,50,107,139,26,236,107,174,58,186,236,70,188,180,215,97,53,226,45,176,154,240,141,129,117,225,109,137,218,226,210,251,25,174,21,157,141,117,197,137,216,151,92,90,206,196,186,235,171,59,9,128,146,179,156,118,34,198,119,201,75,70,108,175,145,179,138,147,25,204,75,135,150,153,229,157,137,35,28,203,240,109,140,51,233,174,54,113,216,219,173,182,217,108,141,215,92,207,62,236,20,245,174,97,248,151,210,50,102,49,209,92,138,227,9,174,80,196,34,185,167,96,162,87,99,52,248,239,93,206,45,74,202,187,20,88,181,173,114,44,197,193,120,204,71,132,139,89,206,55,3,22,173,129,186,236,90,78,204,154,172,90,78,216,205,82,45,39,110,53,2,211,182,166,166,75,108,77,81,77,165,53,116,150,206,205,109,45,59,27,117,214,218,118,52,215,27,102,198,186,218,155,27,245,169,33,178,63,95,147,58,103,87,8,234,215,54,236,26,196,103,23,6,168,206,24,34,204,242,224,73,140,243,181,245,152,207,152,34,99,62,96,86,209,157,92,17,49,158,76,17,104,206,174,5,108,216,47,106,110,152,233,219,127,3,189,58,247,99,88,217,227,176,1,96,0,0,48,153,175,61,173,131,160,247,87,169,142,115,169,187,92,46,125,2,161,75,170,34,90,170,136,150,205,195,86,78,17,107,113,71,82,81,85,105,163,92,231,211,72,223,44,185,237,12,179
]}}

Now, I need to render this image on my react js page, in the following image tag:
//img style={{ width: "50%" }} src={this.state.file} ///

How can I do this, please suggest. Thanks!